# vba convert formula into value if value is >0 in specific range

Tags: vba, excel

A question: I am trying to convert a formula in a specific range into its value once the value of that formula is more than 0 in vba. I have found some results for converting an entire workbook to just it's value, but nothing more detailed than that.

```
Sub ConvertCellsToValues()
         ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
         ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the range in question is **A1** thru **A10.**

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each r In A
        If r.HasFormula And r.Value > 0 Then
            r.Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: I used your macro, however it doesn't seem like it actually converts any formula into a value. I tried combining it with what I already had , as seen below, but then it completely ignored the specified range.
`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
        Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each r In A
        If r.HasFormula And r.Value > 0 Then
            Param.Copy
             Param.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next r
    End Sub`

Comment: **NOT**  *Param.Copy*  use *r.Copy*  etc.

Answer (score 0):

The .Copy and .PasteSpecial work for any range:

```
Sub ConvertCellsToValues(Param as Range)
  Param.Copy
  Param.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```