# How do I get around circular reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help to go around circular refence on my code.

What the code does is copy a value from cell A2 unto a cell in the same row using the date in Row1 as reference. `=IF(C1=$A$1, IF(ISBLANK($A2), ,$A2), )` .
[image]

This code does the job but the problem is when I change the date on Cell A1 to say like September 2, the value on Cell C2 returns to 0, I want it to maintain it's value after changing the date at cell A1.

[image]

This last image would be the ideal output but the code has circular reference which is not ideal as the whole sheet has 365days each row January1 to December31 and has 200rows.
The code `=IF(C1=$A$1, IF(ISBLANK($A2), ,$A2), C2 )`

[image]

Comment: You can't refer the calculation to itself (own cell). What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @P.b I want the value that was in said cell (C2, D2, E2, etc) to remain after I change the date in cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to ask it to do is:
IF my date header matches my date input header, then give me the cell details.
The problem is that when you change the date header it's no longer going to match for different dates and is going to re-evaluate with a 0. That's why this doesn't work.

Anytime you adjust that formula again, it's going to re-evaluate and you're going to be back to square 1.

That's why I can't give you a formula based answer BUT:
When the cell has taken it's reference for that date highlight it (eg. C2), press F2, and then press F9. It'll remove the formula and just leave the value behind. You have to do this before changing the header for A1 again.

If you're savvy, you can turn this into a macro. :)

Comment: there are other people that input data so I want it to be automated that the values don't disappear.

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA? Realistically, you would need to convert your formula to a value once the result was >0. This may be of help to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166527/vba-convert-formula-into-value-if-value-is-0-in-specific-range

You could also take my suggestion above and turn it into a button to do a one click to "save" it as a value. This way it's easy for lots of different skill levels to perform that step.